# Getting list of connected devices and types to a network without connecting

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, ip-address

I'm using `kismet` to get a list of networks nearby and all the devices that are connected to them.

I can get the MAC address off these devices, but I was wondering if it was also possible to get the type of device as well, for instance iPhone 5 (or even more detailed, like iPhone 5 Black). I would not have the credentials to the network.

Alternatively, if I turn my computer in a router, can I determine all devices and types that are in close proximity?

I'm basically wondering if there is a way you can determine all devices that are close.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of an automated way to do this but you can look up MAC addresses to get some information on the device (at least the manufacturer) -- http://www.macvendorlookup.com/

Comment: This will only give me the manufacturer information (like Apple), not the specific device.